# How can I remove this p tag from my json fetch

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, fetch

I'm using React and fetch to get this data from an api I removed the p tag that I had but is still appearing there and that not what I want. I think the text in the json data has a p tag. How I can removed it?[image: Error to be handled]

I'm using fetch on the lifecycle method  componenDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API).then(response => response.json()).then(data => this.setState({ quotes: data}));
  }
```

How can I find & replace the p tag before I added to the state? 
I'm trying to do it right there in the lifecycle method but it keeps throwing me errors

Comment: use JSON API to parse & locate p tag and then remove it

Comment: uses .replace() or .substring()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively to matbous answer using regex, you could just replace the tags directly like this:

```
let demoJSON = {
 field: "<p>Hello World</p>"
}
```

`demoJSON.field.replace('<p>','').replace('</p>', '');`

`console.log(demoJSON.field);`

```
componentDidMount() {
   fetch(API).then(response => response.json()).then(data => this.setState({ 
quotes: data.replace('<p>','').replace('</p>', '')}));
}
```

Should probably work, so should @Matou's answer in his comment. If not, can you share the actual error output so we can help further.

Comment: I added extra information can you please help me some more I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
let demoJSON = {
  field: "<p>Hello World</p>"
}

console.log(demoJSON.field.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ""));
```

Comment: I added extra information can you please help some more I'm stuck

Comment: Depending on how the returned JSON is formatted, you can do the following: 

`componentDidMount() {
  fetch(API).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
  data.field = data.field.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
  this.setState({quotes: data});
  });
}`

Comment: Doesn't work it throw me an error says: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined